# How to match height of 2 divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="order-summary">
  <ul>
     <li class="li-summary"><div class="summary-left">Name:</div><div class="summary-right">Ehtesham Ali</div></li>
     <li class="li-summary"><div class="summary-left">Delivery Address:</div><div class="summary-right">House 1, Street 1</div></li>              
  </ul>
</div>
```

summary-left and summary-right have height to 100%: I want summary-right to match the height of summary-left.

The summary-left has a background color and summary-right does not. li-summary has a border-bottom. So when summary-right goes to 2 lines, background color on summary-right does not fill 100%

```
.order-summary{
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  margin: 80px auto;
  font-family: 'Lato','Open Sans','Helvetica Neue','Arial','San-serif';
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom:0;
}
.summary-left{
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 10px;
}
.summary-right{
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
.li-summary{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

[Image of the Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AePbO.png)

Solution : Easiest way I found to solve my issue was to add a gradient background

```
.li-summary{
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, #fbfbfb, #fbfbfb 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #fbfbfb, #fbfbfb 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 100%);}
```

Comment: share the CSS also

Comment: Please adjust your post with proper grammar. As it stands, it is difficult to figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: Use flex box it will sort even height rows automatically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44846068/css-equal-height-columns

Comment: added css to the original post, also the photo of the issue, flex is not working with my code

Comment: Edited original post to add my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using jquery:

```
// get height of left summary and set right summary to the same on page load
var summaryLeftHeight = $(".summary-left").height();
$(".summary-right").css("height", summaryLeftHeight + "px");

// add this to make sure they have the same height on page resize 
$(window).on("resize", function(){
   var summaryLeftHeight = $(".summary-left").height();
   $(".summary-right").css("height", summaryLeftHeight + "px");
});
```

You can also do this by using http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/ : 
Include the cdn in your code

```
<script src="jquery.matchHeight.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Updated HTML (I added the class="summary" to each element that you want to be the same height):

```
<div class="order-summary">
  <ul>
     <li class="li-summary">
        <div class="summary summary-left">Name:</div>
        <div class="summary summary-right">Ehtesham Ali</div>
     </li>
     <li class="li-summary">
        <div class="summary summary-left">Delivery Address:</div>
        <div class="summary summary-right">House 1, Street 1</div>
     </li>              
  </ul>
</div>
```

And initialize the code in your js file or in a script tag

```
$(function() {
    $('.summary').matchHeight();
});
```

The plugin selects the element with the largest height by default but you can select a target by selecting the option target, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.summary').matchHeight({
        target: $('.summary-left') // using summary left as the target 
    });
});
```

Comment: This is also a workable option, but keep in mind that this isn't the ideal way if you think about performance.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dei79/3965331 this is the easiest work around that i have found so car can any of you help me understand how to select the larger height instead of smaller one

Comment: @EhteshAmAlIi the plugin should automatically select the element with the larger height, but I have edited my answer to show how you can use the plugin to select a target element: Also refer here to see the other options: https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height

Comment: yes i tried this plugin it works the same as the one I gave, it selects the smaller height and matches that one, my smaller height is 44 px and bigger one is 70px but first column has 44px on both sides , so idk if it uses the height on first column

Comment: @EhteshAmAlIi I made a codepen, tell me if that is what you are looking for https://codepen.io/punsammy/pen/zJdzYd

Comment: yes something like that, but i want the background of delivery address to be 100% in the box, right now it is not filling the box as its height is not matching the height on the right side

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox for this one see [Set height of CSS flex elements to the same amount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673701/set-height-of-css-flex-elements-to-the-same-amount)

I've made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nje09Lq6/15/) with your code see you can see for yourself.

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

li{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: your fiddle is not working check this with more data https://jsfiddle.net/nje09Lq6/5/

Comment: You are correct I forgot some extra flex and general CSS. I've changef the url in my answer or you can view it here https://jsfiddle.net/nje09Lq6/10/

Comment: now the left one doesnot have the same width, Name is bigger than Delivery Address, that messes up the whole table

Comment: I've changed this also for you, see https://jsfiddle.net/nje09Lq6/15/
Is this good enough for you or is there still something missing?

Comment: it is working on fiddle but it is still messing up the table on the website, idk why 
Thanks though

Comment: Check out all the CSS in my fiddle. I've also needed to remove height: 100% in your CSS.

Comment: yes i changed all the css, it does the work like covers up with the background color but the width is all messed up, but the same code works fine on fiddle

Comment: yes exactly like that, but why is it not working on website http://leathercraft.pk/order-submitted.php

Comment: @EhteshAmAlIi I added the class summary to each element and then I called matchHeight on .summary instead. I have updated my answer!