# Avada Tabs styling

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have some Wordpress Avada Tabs here:
https://www.judoclubsihltal.ch/turnieranmeldungen/

Unfortunately they all have a different heigth:
https://www.screencast.com/t/cwQ65Y9g

So i would like to have the `<a>` part the same heigth as the `<li>`.
I already tried with display: block, but unfortunately i did not succeed.

```
#post-6702 .nav .nav-tabs li a{
    display: block;
}
```

Best Regards

Florin

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673701/set-height-of-css-flex-elements-to-the-same-amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply give them a fixed height.

```
.tab-link {
    height: 50px;
}
```